# SQL syntax error in "insert into 'keys'(a,b,c,d,e) values(?,?,?,?,?)"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
    String requiredKeyword = request.getParameter("KeyWord");
    String textBookCode = request.getParameter("BookCode");
    String pageNumbers= request.getParameter("PageNumbers");
    String definition = request.getParameter("Definition");


    PrintWriter show = response.getWriter();

    try 
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection dbConnection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/main_data","root","");
        System.out.println(" Connection Created Successfully ");

        PreparedStatement prepSt =(PreparedStatement) dbConnection.prepareStatement(" insert into 'keys'(requiredKeyword,noOfPages,textBookCode,pageNumbers,definition) values(?,?,?,?,?) ");
        System.out.println(" Statement Prepared ");

        int num=1,i=0;

        prepSt.setString(1,requiredKeyword);
        prepSt.setInt(2,num);
        prepSt.setString(3,textBookCode);
        prepSt.setString(4,pageNumbers);
        prepSt.setString(5,definition);
        try
        {
            i= prepSt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(" Executed ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            show.println(e);
        }

        if(i>0)
            show.println(" Inserted Successfully ");

        dbConnection.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        show.print(e);
    }
```

```
ERROR : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
''keys'(requiredKeyword,noOfPages,textBookCode,pageNumbers,definition) values('da' at line 1
```

Comment: -1 It should be **plainly obvious** that a `MySQLSyntaxErrorException` is caused by incorrect syntax in a MySQL query. Check the syntax of your prepared statement and the generated SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using standard quotes instead of backticks for escaping the MySql reserved word [`KEYS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Change the table name to any non-reserved word so that the quotes can be removed.

Comment: Thank You Sir , now it's done (Y)